# htaccess redirect to a new domain hosted in a subfolder

Tags: redirect, subdirectory

I have tried unsuccessfully to 301 redirect from the old domain to the new domain. The domains are hosted on the same account and the new domain is in a subfolder of the old domain:

public_html (where the old domain is)
public_html/newdomain.com (where the new domain is hosted)

I tried:

Redirect 301 / https://www.newdomain.com/

But a standard 301 redirect seems to become recursive and seems to break the new site.

I even tried, not successfully, creating a folder, say /social on the old domain and trying the following:

Redirect 301 /social/ https://www.newdomain.com/social/

which fails to load the legitimate URL on the newdomain.com even if it is not coming from the old domain.

I am able to implement a solution but not knowledgeable enough to create the needed expression, if it is at all possible. Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched and found a solution for my problem. The sites in the question were both on WordPress platform. I have found several plugins that will do redirection very easily. The one I am using is called Redirection, a search on the WordPress.org plugins page will show you this and other similar plugins for this purpose.